# Find maximum and minimum eigenvalues of symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matlab

I have to find maximum and minimum eigenvalues of symmetric matrix. First that I've done is tridiagonalize it and now it looks like
$$
{A_{n \times n}} = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{a_1}&{b_2}&{}&{}&{}\\
{b_2}&{a_2}&{b_3}&{}&{}\\
{}&{b_3}&{\ddots}&{\ddots}&{}\\
{}&{}&{\ddots}&{\ddots}&{b_{n}}\\
{}&{}&{}&{b_{n}}&{a_n}
\end{array}} \right]
$$
I have to do it with some kind of recursion but can't find anything that can help me to understand how to do it.

Comment: Have a look at this question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/131527/eigenvalues-of-symmetric-tridiagonal-matrices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is that the task is formulated not properly. I thought I should use some properties of tridiagonal matrices but I don't. To find max and min eigenvalues it's enough to use simple iterations:
$$
x^{(0)} = (x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)^T
$$ 
$x^{(0)}$ is a random vector.
$$
x^{(k+1)} = A \frac{x^{(k)}}{\alpha_k}
$$
Where $\alpha_k$ is the maximum element of $x^{(k)}$ in absolute value.
So, $\lambda_{max}=\alpha_n$ is the max eigenvalue in absolute value.

To find the minimum eigenvalue:
$$
x^{(k+1)} = A^{-1} \frac{x^{(k)}}{\alpha_k}
$$
Where $\alpha_k$ is the maximum element of $x^{(k)}$ in absolute value.
So, $\lambda_{min}=\frac{1}{\alpha_n}$ is the min eigenvalue in absolute value.